# In which situation can I use getPort() in a DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm using DatagramSockets to build a application and I stacked in a point of the code that I should identify which port my socket was bound. So in this part of my code:

```
        dnsConnection = new DatagramSocket();
        
        byte[] date = "\nSend me a available server IP!".getBytes();
        pkg = new DatagramPacket(date, date.length, addr, port);
        
        status.append("\nTrying to send the message to: " + addr.getHostAddress());

        dnsConnection.send(pkg);
        localPort = dnsConnection.getPort();
        
        status.append("\nRequest has been sent to: " + addr.getHostAddress());
        status.append("\nthrough the port: " + localPort);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the port in which my socket was bound using the method **getPort()**. Reading the API, we have this statement:

> public int getPort()
>
> Returns the port number to which this socket is connected. Returns -1 if the socket is not connected.

In this sense I continue to search an alternative and I found the method **getLocalPort()** and in the API:

> public int getLocalPort()
>
> Returns the port number on the local host to which this socket is bound.

Then using getLocalPort() I could have gotten the port in which my socket is bind, and I understood that getPort() is probably to get the port that the socket is connected, i.e., the port of the host in which I want to send information. After all this, grew up a question on my head:

As UDP is conectionless, in which moment can I use getPort() to recovery the port in which my socket is connected?

Maybe I understood wrong and getPort() is not related with the remote host, if I'm wrong please clarify-me.

That is.
Thanks.
Pablo

Comment: You can call `connect` to give a default address, and then `getPort`/`getInetAddress` will return that address.

Comment: But UDP is not connectionless? How can I connect to some host? The method `connect` will keep the connection open?

Comment: All it does is set the default destination address.

Comment: `connect` in UDP statically assigns a remote IP/Port to the socket. It does not actually connect the socket to the peer, like it does in TCP. This allows you to specify the target peer once on the socket itself rather than on each individual packet, and it allows the socket to ignore any inbound packets that are not sent from that same peer. So you can have a similar effect as TCP, as far as peer management is concerned - all packets you send go to the same peer, and you are guaranteed that any packet received came from that peer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call dnsConnection.send(pkg), the DatagramPacket pkg includes information of the IP address of the remote host, and the port number on the remote host. When you later call dnsConnection.getPort(), it just returns the remote port number of the last sent packet, which is local information.